# Obter informações do cliente

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Esta pode parecer uma pergunta boba, mas estou meio encrencado em um problema aqui.

Preciso recolher através do browser alguma informação que me ajude a identificar o cliente que esteja navegando. 
Eu já sei que o endereço MAC eu não irei conseguir. Porém seria possível conseguir algum identificador do navegador instalado? Talvez algum ID de instalação, ou algo que me ajude a identificar o cliente que está utilizando minha aplicação?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

No `C#` em **Assembly:  System.Web** tem a classe `Request`, que você pode usar para capturar varias informações do **Client**.

> Por exemplo o IP.

```
 String IP = Request.UserHostAddress;
```

[Veja a lista de Propriedade.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
HttpBrowserCapabilities bc = Request.Browser;
Response.Write("<p>Browser Capabilities:</p>");
Response.Write("Type = " + bc.Type + "<br>");
Response.Write("Name = " + bc.Browser + "<br>");
Response.Write("Version = " + bc.Version + "<br>");
Response.Write("Major Version = " + bc.MajorVersion + "<br>");
Response.Write("Minor Version = " + bc.MinorVersion + "<br>");
Response.Write("Platform = " + bc.Platform + "<br>");
Response.Write("Is Beta = " + bc.Beta + "<br>");
Response.Write("Is Crawler = " + bc.Crawler + "<br>");
Response.Write("Is AOL = " + bc.AOL + "<br>");
Response.Write("Is Win16 = " + bc.Win16 + "<br>");
Response.Write("Is Win32 = " + bc.Win32 + "<br>");
Response.Write("Supports Frames = " + bc.Frames + "<br>");
Response.Write("Supports Tables = " + bc.Tables + "<br>");
Response.Write("Supports Cookies = " + bc.Cookies + "<br>");
Response.Write("Supports VB Script = " + bc.VBScript + "<br>");
Response.Write("Supports JavaScript = " + bc.JavaScript + "<br>");
Response.Write("Supports Java Applets = " + bc.JavaApplets + "<br>");
Response.Write("Supports ActiveX Controls = " + bc.ActiveXControls + "<br>");
Response.Write("CDF = " + bc.CDF + "<br>");
```

[Detalhes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httprequest.browser(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: IP é algo muito simples. Eu precisaria de mais.

Comment: você não especificou seu seu **mais** ...

Comment: fiz a minha própria resposta abaixo

Answer (score 1):

Achei o que estava procurando.
Irei utilizar uma técnica baseada em [FingerPrint](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122372/is-browser-fingerprinting-a-viable-technique-for-identifying-anonymous-users) com um [plugin](http://valve.github.io/blog/2013/07/14/anonymous-browser-fingerprinting/) já feito para tal.

A partir de N variáveis contidas no browser é possível gerar um hash como um identificador único para aquela máquina.

Irei utilizar também o [Evercookie](https://github.com/samyk/evercookie) para guardar as informações.

Espero que ajude.

Comment: O plugin do fingerprint me ajudará a criar um identificador único sem nenhum esforço. Não creio que o Request.Browser poderia fazer o mesmo.